# In if controller ( if price value is greater than 500 we need to choose Home page or if lesser than 500 choose Purchase the flight )

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

[image: This is img give correct if controller code]

Can give the correct code. If price is greater than 500 we need to choose Home Page or Price lesser than 500
we need to choose Purchase the flight

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need 2 If Controllers (or eventually a [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) to avoid copy and paste)
2. The "Purchase" and "Home" samplers should be moved to be the children of the respective If Controllers
3. You will need to use a function like [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as If Controller expects the function or varible evaluating to `true`

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)